# Understanding Emacs' versioning system

Tags: emacs

Last night a [new pre-test](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu-emacs/2014-04/msg00000.html) Emacs version was [released](http://emacsformacosx.com/builds) (OS X link). The **pre-test** version is `24.3.90` and the current **nightly** version number is `24.4.50.1`.

This made me wonder, what version number are the subsequent releases of **pre-test** versions supposed to converge to, and how is this version number determined?  For example would the **pre-test** end on `24.4` and then there will be a new **stable** `24.4` version? or will they converge to some other number of the `23.4.*` series since the nightlies are *already* moving beyond `24.4`?

Also, what is the difference between the **pre-test**, **release-candidate** and **preview** versions?

Finally, when I go on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Emacs), Wikipedia highlights a **current preview** version (`24.2-rc2`) even though we have *already* have a **stable** version (`24.3`) that is more recent than the preview version. Why highlight a **preview** version *after* a **stable** version has already been released?

Answer (score 3):

## Previews, pre-tests and release candidates

**“preview”** is Wikipedia “slang”, and seems to refer to Release Candidates.  You'll need to ask the authors of the corresponding article, why the preview versions are listed.  I presume that whoever edited the article to announce the Emacs releases simply forgot to update the the “preview” section as well.

**Pre-tests** are pre-release versions intended for public testing, distributed as tarball from the GNU FTP servers.  While approaching a release, pre-tests are frequently released to get testing and feedback from the community.

**Release candidates** are simply the last pre-tests immediately before the final release.  Roughly speaking, a pre-test becomes a release candidate if the maintainers feel that Emacs is now stable enough for a public release.

## Version numbering

The current Emacs trunk always has the version number `X.Y.50`, where `X.Y` is the major and minor version of the last release.  On the road to the *first* pre-test, the trunk is frozen for features, and only bug fixes are committed.  With the first pre-test, the trunk is moved to a special branch, and it's version number is increased, to the version number of the *next* release.

The subsequent release process happens on the special branch.  The first pre-test gets the version `X.Y.90`, where `X.Y` is again the major and minor version of the last release.

The final release then gets the version number `X.(Y+1)`, and is tagged.

Hence, before the first pre-test of Emacs 24.4, the nightly builds had the version number `24.3.50`.  With the first pre-test `24.3.90`, the nightly builds became what will be Emacs `24.5` in some far future and consequently now have the version number `24.4.50`.

The pre-test versions will increase as subsequent pre-tests are released (e.g. `24.3.90`, `24.3.91`, etc.) and ultimately converge to `24.4` which is the final release.

## Disclaimer

I'm no Emacs developer, so the above may be inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks, but some of this is not consistent at least with what I have seen. The nightly version number was already `24.4.50.1` on April 6 (I know this since I downloaded my first nightly on that date and `M-x version` returns `24.4.50.1` for that nightly), even though the first pre-test for 24.4 came out today.

Comment: I presume the pre-test was already planned by then, and trunk was already moved to a special branch.  But as said, I may be mistaken.

Comment: Plans have changed since that answer was written : emacs after 24.4 will be 25.1.